# drawimage() not working in js

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I want to draw an image in javascript and i dont know why its not drawing. I've look on the interweb for an answer but I cant find one. Here is the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;
var playerimg = new Image();

function setup(){
    render();
}

function render()
{
    playerimg.onload = drawcharacter();
}

function drawcharacter(){
    ctx.drawImage(playerimg, 340, 240, 50, 50);
}

playerimg.src = "playersrc.png";
window.onload = render();
render();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Include as much detail into your question as possible.

Comment: if you intialize playerImg first, you can already attach an event on it, no need to wait for document load. Then, try to set its src after you attached the event (which is not the case here)

Comment: May be `playerimg.onload` triggered earlier than you redefine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
playerimg.onload = drawcharacter();
```

Your intention seems to be to make `drawcharacter` the onload handler for `playerimg`. But what this line does actually do, is *immediately* execute `drawcharacter()` and then assign the *return value* as onload handler of `playerimg`. The function doesn't return anything, so your onload handler gets set to `undefined`.

To properly assign a function as an onload handler, omit the parenthesis:

```
playerimg.onload = drawcharacter;
```